# What is the Best Practice for dropping the support of old browsers?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8

If you are making a Website which will not support IE8 and all browsers older then that. Whats the best practice for that? Should there just be an alert and the Site should show anyways (and look bad) or should the site completly be replaced by a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally the approach I would take is similar to that of viewing a website on a mobile device, sometimes you will get a warning saying the website is not compatible. I.E like you said replace the website with a warning, possibly suggesting that the user updates their browser. Hope this helps!